# Moving a box using tf

Tags: rviz, tf-broadcaster, collision-object, planning-scene, position

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi to all,

I try to move a box in my planning scene using a tf-frame. But it's not working at the moment.

I insert the box as shown in the moveit-tutorial and giving it a tf-frame additionally like this:

```
 /* The id of the object is used to identify it. */
  co_box.id = "box1";
  co_box.header.frame_id = "//box_frame";
```

If I now insert the box, it is correctly inserted at the position and orientation I publish in my tf-broadcaster. But when I move the frame in the broadcaster, I can see the frame moving in Rviz but not the box.

What can I do here. Is the box not correctly linked to the tf-frame or do I constantly need to update the planning scene.
I'm really stuck here. I would really appreciate if somebody could help me out.

Edit (the code for inserting the box and trying to move):

```
 // insert BOX
  // ^^^^^^^^^^

  moveit_msgs::CollisionObject co_box;
  co_box.header.frame_id = "//box_frame";

  /* The id of the object is used to identify it. */
  co_box.id = "box1";
  // co_box.header.frame_id = "box_frame";

  /* Define a box to add to the world. */
  shape_msgs::SolidPrimitive primitive;
  primitive.type = primitive.BOX;
  primitive.dimensions.resize(3);
  primitive.dimensions[0] = 1.0;
  primitive.dimensions[1] = 0.2;
  primitive.dimensions[2] = 0.4;

  /* A pose for the box (specified relative to frame_id) */
  geometry_msgs::Pose box_pose;
  box_pose.orientation.w = 1.0;
  box_pose.position.x =  0.0;
  box_pose.position.y =  0.0;
  box_pose.position.z =  0.0;

  co_box.primitives.push_back(primitive);
  co_box.primitive_poses.push_back(box_pose);
  co_box.operation = co_box.ADD;



  std::vector<moveit_msgs::CollisionObject> collision_objects;
  collision_objects.push_back(co_box);

  ROS_INFO("Add collision objects into the world");
  planning_scene_interface.addCollisionObjects(collision_objects);
  /* Sleep so we have time to see the object in RViz */
  sleep(10.0);

  while(ros::ok()){
       co_box.operation = co_box.MOVE;
       sleeprate.sleep();
  }
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/206229/moving-a-box-using-tf/) by [bluefish](https://answers.ros.org/users/21682/bluefish/) on ROS Answers with karma: 236 on 2015-03-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

Finally I managed to solve this issue. If anybody is facing the same problem, here is my approach, which works for me:

```
ros::Publisher collision_object_publisher = node_handle.advertise<moveit_msgs::CollisionObject>("collision_object", 1);
  while(collision_object_publisher.getNumSubscribers() < 1)
  {
      ros::WallDuration sleep_t(0.5);
      sleep_t.sleep();
  }

  moveit_msgs::CollisionObject co;
  co.header.frame_id = "box_frame";
  co.id = "box";
  geometry_msgs::Pose pose;
  // pose.orientation.w = 1.0;
  shape_msgs::SolidPrimitive primitive;
  primitive.type = primitive.BOX;
  primitive.dimensions.resize(3);
  primitive.dimensions[0] = 0.1;
  primitive.dimensions[1] = 0.1;
  primitive.dimensions[2] = 0.1;
  co.primitives.push_back(primitive);
  co.primitive_poses.push_back(pose);
  co.operation = co.ADD;
  collision_object_publisher.publish(co);


  sleep(5);


  moveit_msgs::CollisionObject move_object;
  move_object.id = "box";
  move_object.header.frame_id = "box_frame";
  move_object.primitive_poses.push_back(pose);
  move_object.operation = move_object.MOVE;

  ros::Rate loop_rate(100);

  while(ros::ok()){
    collision_object_publisher.publish(move_object);
    loop_rate.sleep();
    ROS_INFO("Another loop");
  }
```

Thanks @dornhege for the hints!!

---

Originally posted by [bluefish](https://answers.ros.org/users/21682/bluefish/) with karma: 236 on 2015-05-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you put it into the planning scene, it's stored there in the planning frame for planning, so if it is moved, you need to update it. Use the MOVE operation in CollisionObject to only supply a new pose without resending geometry all the time.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2015-05-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bluefish](https://answers.ros.org/users/21682/bluefish/) on 2015-05-07**:
Hi! Thanks for your answer!
I tried `co_box.operation = co_box.MOVE;` constantly called in a while-loop but it doesn't seem to work.
Do have to add an `planning_scene_interface`-command? Something like `planning_scene.update`? But I can't find an appropriate one...

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2015-05-07**:
What are you sending?

**Comment by [bluefish](https://answers.ros.org/users/21682/bluefish/) on 2015-05-07**:
as I wrote above: I send `co_box.operation = co_box.MOVE;`

**Comment by [bluefish](https://answers.ros.org/users/21682/bluefish/) on 2015-05-07**:
Or do you mean how I send the whole collision_object to the planning scene? This I do pretty much exactly as explained in the moveit c++-tutorial.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2015-05-07**:
There are two ways: As part of a planning scene update or directly as an object. I have only tried the planning scene update, although I assume that both should have the same functionality.

**Comment by [bluefish](https://answers.ros.org/users/21682/bluefish/) on 2015-05-07**:
I updated the question with the complete code for inserting the box and the try to move it. Could you tell what code excatly I have to add? (What was your code for updating the planning scene?)

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2015-05-07**:
I haven't worked with the planning scene interface. I send these directly as a planning scene message. However, I believe it should work. I have also used the MOVE operation in there.

**Comment by [bluefish](https://answers.ros.org/users/21682/bluefish/) on 2015-05-07**:
Hmm. But I tried it and cannot see any movement... As before the tf-frame is moving but not the object... :(

**Comment by [bluefish](https://answers.ros.org/users/21682/bluefish/) on 2015-05-07**:
@dornhege: could you maybe post the code snippet of inserting and moving objects via planning scene messages? Would really appreciate!